# How would I compare different times with different formats using dayjs and jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, time, calendar, dayjs

I'm new to JavaScript and they're cranking along with the pace of the program I'm in. What I'm trying to do is "create" a calendar app that uses dayjs to compare against the time windows (8am-5pm) and change the classes to effect the styling of the page. I'm looking for direction on how to go about this problem. My original idea was to try to compare the time recorded by dayjs against different named IDs in the HTML, "0800" "1300" and so forth but I'm hitting a roadblock and none of the things I've searched have given me an answer that works for what I'm trying to do. I'm having difficulty comparing the dayjs documented time vs. the variable and I'm positive it has to do with my limited understanding. Here is a couple samples for context.

```
 <div id="900" class="times row time-block past">
        <div class="col-2 col-md-1 hour text-center py-3">9AM</div>
        <textarea class="col-8 col-md-10 description" rows="3"> </textarea>
        <button class="btn saveBtn col-2 col-md-1" aria-label="save">
          <i class="fas fa-save" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
      </div>

      <!-- Example of a present time block. The "present" class adds a red background color. -->
      <div id="1000" class="times row time-block present">
        <div class="col-2 col-md-1 hour text-center py-3">10AM</div>
        <textarea class="col-8 col-md-10 description" rows="3"> </textarea>
        <button class="btn saveBtn col-2 col-md-1" aria-label="save">
          <i class="fas fa-save" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
```

```
var today = dayjs();
var calendarTimes = document.querySelectorAll(".times")
$('#currentDay').text(today.format('dddd, MMM D hh:mmA'));

var onePm = $('#1300');
var eightAm = $('#800');
var fivePm = $('#1700');

fivePm = dayjs("1700", "h");
```

I've been trying to test different things in the dev tools such as today < fivePm to see how it would register. Dev Tools returned NaN so I know my formatting is all kinds of wrong. My goal is to be able to have it return true/false based on time and create an if/else if/else statement to format all the windows in different colors based on the time. Thank you!